Can we say "under 100 days"?
Is it grammatically correct to say "Under 100 days until Halloween"?
I would rather use "Less than 100 days until Halloween" but I'd like to know if the first sentence is grammatically incorrect and why.
To me, it feels a little clunky and I have tried free grammar checkers but they can't identify anything being wrong or weirdly phrased. Bing's AI chatbot thought it was understandable, although it could be written more naturally, yet it couldn't tell why.

Something can be grammatical and understandable at the same time but in English the correct collocation can make the difference between sounding weird or idiomatic.
There are under 100 days to Halloween ❎
There are less than 100 days to Halloween ✅
However, the FORMAL (and mostly outdated) version is fewer because day is a countable noun; also note the plural verb are.
There are fewer than 100 days to Halloween ✅

PREP.  in a/the ~ We hope to finish the job in a few days.

We can use the phrase less than when we refer to the period within a single unit of time, e.g. less than a day, less than a year etc...
In less than a month it will be Halloween ✅
The preposition under is also used in a similar way

And with just under a month before election day, the candidates are neck and neck. ✅
In some countries you cannot legally drive a car if you are under [the age of] 18. ✅
“Now, because of the way it's reported—you've got this constant 24-hours-a-day media—it may seem to people that it's a lot longer than just under a week. But actually, it's just under a week. And in just under a week, there is a massive amount that has already been achieved.” George Bush, NYT, March 28 2003.


Why do "under a month" and "under 18" both get checks but "under 100 days" gets an x? I tend to agree that it feels better but it also feels very arbitrary.

@user3067860 hours, days, weeks are plural and countable. A week, a month, a year are individual units of time. You can say "I'll be back in under an hour but "less than" is more idiomatic. We don't normally say: "I'll be back in under 3 hours”; it's "I'll be back in [less than] 3 hours. OR "I'll be back in a few hours" (without saying the precise number, because "few" already suggests 2 or 3)

But I feel pretty comfortable saying "everyone who is under eighteen years old", and even "I should have it done in under two hours" feels fine. Less formal than "less than", but natural enough for casual language. Vs the OP's example does feel unnatural.

@user3067860 post an answer explaining why "in under two hours" sounds OK but not so with "under a hundred days" I'll upvote if it is well-argued.

We use these 3 quantifiers differently:

Fewer is used with countable nouns
Less is used with uncountable nouns (things measured in quantity)
Under can be used with both countable and uncountable nouns to indicate a limit, target or threshold

"Under 100 days" isn't correct in the context of your example because there is no limit or threshold. Halloween itself isn't a 'target', it's just a fixed date that is coming no matter what. If you said "you must prepare for Christmas in under 100 days" that would be okay because you are imposing 100 days as a target for your preparations and it doesn't even mean that Christmas is in 100 days.
Mari-Lou's answer is correct in saying that the insistence on 'fewer' for countable nouns is now largely ignored in informal speech, but this isn't the only reason it doesn't sound idiomatic here. 'Days' are technically a countable noun, but confusingly they are also units of time which is uncountable - we measure time. Yes, we measure it in minutes, hours, days, weeks, months etc, but whenever we talk about time counting down we treat it as an uncountable concept. You can say "you have less than a day" which could mean you have hours, minutes or seconds; you can also switch from measuring it in months to weeks, which are uncorrelated.
So, in short - don't use 'under', because you're not imposing a target or working to a deadline; don't use 'fewer', because you're measuring time. You should use 'less'.

Although strictly non-standard, ‘less’ is widely used for countable quantities as well as uncountable ones.  (For example, supermarket express lanes are almost always of the form ‘10 Items Or Less’.)  I suspect that ‘fewer’ is starting to die.  (And if you think that would be a sad loss, you might want to consider why we've never made that distinction with ‘more’…)

@gidds That actually makes me wonder if that's a holdover from older English or something, and if there used to be a companion word to "more" that's now obsolete because it went through the same shift?

@Idran I've wondered that, too.  The obvious choice would be something like *manyer (and *manyest), but I haven't found anything like that.  (Except on some obviously AI-generated ‘educational’ sites…  Wiktionary has some similar-looking Middle English words, but they're unrelated.)

@gidds Never made that distinction? Of course we do - we have the word greater which is only used to compare things that are numerically (therefore countable) greater.

@Astralbee But ‘greater’ doesn't mean quite the same, and doesn't require or even imply a countable target — that needs a form such as ‘greater number of’.

@gidds Apart from the exceptions of abstract concepts (eg the greater good) and the use in place names (eg Greater London) which is listed as a separate use in dictionaries anyway, can you give me an example of 'greater' being used to compare anything under than numbers, quantities, or measurements?

@Astralbee Are you asking for an uncountable use of ‘greater’ that's neither abstract nor concrete (a measurement)?  That seems a little unfair…  :-)
